# What is char buffer[0x4000] doing?

Tags: libssh2

The libssh2.org example:
http://www.libssh2.org/examples/ssh2_exec.html

has the line:
char buffer[0x4000];

What is this line doing?

Comment: Exactly "which part"? Bread down the problem into pieces, they are easy to examine/understand/reason-about that way :)

Answer (score 1):

The code allocates a buffer of 16KiB. `0x4000` means 4000 in hexadecimal, which is 16384 in decimal.